# How to get access of document object of a window opened with window.open?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom, browser

I open a website in a new tab through javascript by writing the following code in the browser console:

```
var win = window.open("http://staging.redefinewebs.in/wildgoose-const/wp-admin/post-new.php", "mywin", '');
```

Now I want to add text in a field in the newly opened tab. But for that I need the access to `win.document`. When I write `win.document` in the console I get the following error:

`Error: Permission denied to access property "document"`

This error doesn't appear if I open other websites in new tab. So,

How to get access of document object of a window opened in a new tab with window.open?

Comment: You cannot write to a document on a remote site unless its specifically been written to allow you to do so, that page has not, so you can't.  The only alternative is to proxy the page with a server side script.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access a child window's DOM, if it violates the Same Origin Policy.

You can access the DOM of a child window, only if the following three conditions are satisfied.

- Both windows have same protocol (http/https)
- Both windows have same host (google.com and news.google.com are different)
- Both windows have same port (google.com:80 and google.com:443 are different)

Answer (score 3):

> How to get access of document object of a window opened in a new tab with window.open?

If the window is opening a document from *a different origin*, you don't; cross-origin access is denied by the browser because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). From the error in your question, that would seem to be the case here.

If the window contains a document from the same origin, you can access it as you've shown; but note that it may still be loading immediately after you call `window.open` and you might need to wait for it to finish doing so, perhaps with the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: I somehow succeeded in having access to document with gmail.com when I was logged in.

Comment: @user31782: I suspect that was observation error (for instance, perhaps you were working in the console of a gmail.com page?).

Comment: No. If just open a new blank tab in firefox and open gmail with window.open I can access it's document object. May be my new tab is associated with google server?

Comment: @user31782: If you mean from the console, the console is special.