# Fill a form from another website JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to fill a form from another website, but I have an error and I don't understand why.

My JS's Function :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function rempliFormulair(url) {
    var fenetrePopup = window.open(url);
 fenetrePopup.getElementsByName("NameText").value = "MyLogin";
    fenetrePopup.getElementsByName("NameForm").submit();
  }

  </script>
```

There is my Form :

```
<form name = "NameForm" class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  <input id = "idText" type="text" name="NameText" value="">
    <input id = "azee" type="submit" name="submit" value="aze">
</form>
```

My error:

> Uncaught TypeError: fenetrePopup.getElementsByName is not a function at rempliFormulair

Comment: try `fenetrePopup.document.getElementsByName`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but nothing better :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: fenetrePopup.getElementsByName is not a function
>   at rempliFormulair

`fenetrePopup` is a reference to *pop-window* object.  You need to access the `document` object in the same. Also you can only access the document [if the origin is same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637728/how-to-get-access-of-document-object-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open).

Secondly, `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`,

Try

```
fenetrePopup.document.getElementsByName("NameText")[0].value = "MyLogin";
fenetrePopup.document.getElementsByName("NameForm")[0].submit();
```

or using `querySelector`

```
var doc = fenetrePopup.document;
doc.querySelector("[name='NameText']").value = "MyLogin";
doc.querySelector("[name='NameForm']").submit();
```

**Note**

This will only work if the `url` is in the **same origin**.

**Edit**

You also need to wait for the `onload` event of the child `window`

```
fenetrePopup.onload = function(){
    var doc = fenetrePopup.document;
    doc.querySelector("[name='NameText']").value = "MyLogin";
    doc.querySelector("[name='NameForm']").submit();
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what the origin is. I put what you told me but i have an other Error :

Comment: Sorry, I pressed Enter : My error is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at rempliFormulair

Comment: @C.attia which means that there is no element named `NameText` in the popup. Please share the markup of the popup.

Comment: The popup is a page named mypage.php, In this page, I only have a Form :`<form name = "NameForm" class="" action="index.html" method="post">
<input id = "idText" type="text" name="NameText" value="">
<input id = "azee" type="submit" name="submit" value="aze">
</form>`

Comment: @C.attia then it should have worked, can you share the output of `console.log(fenetrePopup.document)`

Comment: There is the result of console.log(fenetrePopup.document) : `<html> <head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: I don't know.. I tried with another website and I have the same result

Comment: @C.attia You need to wait for the onload event of the child window, see the updates.