# How to make Linkedin add to profile button auto fill data from my Rails Api app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, linkedin-api, autofill

It seems LinkedIn has changed the previous autofulfill button.

https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/

My question is. Is it possible, somehow to fill the form fields with the information so the user can check the info and make the final click?

In my case, I need to add user name, certificate name and add url of the diploma.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly something you can do with Javascript. But I haven't worked with this Linkedin feature at all. But if it's a popup that's opened, you should be able to target it, fill in the fields.

[Edit]

Typescript compiles down into javascript. Here is a related question: [Fill a form from another website JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903410/fill-a-form-from-another-website-js?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: how? I'm using Angular 6 for the front-end so I'm not working with JavaScript but with TypeScript